# Modx: Writing form data into database but table only allow one record and does not update

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I am using formit in modx to create a form for the user to fill in. I then created a snippet to store the data from the form so that I can write it into my database. I followed closely to Bob's guide: http://bobsguides.com/custom-db-tables.html and I have searched online where similar approach has been made. However, my problem is that only one entry is stored each time. In other words, my table has only one record despite the fact that more than one user has filled the form and the record does not get overwritten. For new record to be stored, the current record must first be deleted. I am not sure what might be causing this problem. Makes no sense? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: No suggestions without code. Show code fragment from your snippet for saving to database.

Comment: Only guesses without code as Vasis suggests. My 'guess'' is that you are trying to set the ID of the record and/or are using an update statement rather than an insert. i.e. saving an existing object rather than creating a new one.